Cartoon about a robot that comes out of a pool
I saw this cartoon as a kid(80's).  All I can remember is that there was a pool that split open and a robot would come out and help defeat the bad guys.  I want to say it came on during the block with Thundercats and Silverhawks.

Probably not what you're talking about but in Thunderbirds one of the rockets came out from under the pool on a regular basis. A Kids show, more puppets then Cartoons though.

I think it is Tranzor Z, as the intro on YouTube shows the robot emerging from a swimming pool.  I vaguely remember this as well, I think it tagged along on the Voltron success.

I got the hint on where to look from this forum post.

This is totally it.  I had forgotten about the elbow cannons, but once I saw them, man, it flooded back to me.  Great job, and thank you!

I believe this came out in the 70's-80's era,if i'm not mistaken it's called "MESSENGER", and it also played in Spanish a lot also called "EL MESSENGER".

Hi. Welcome to Movies & TV - can you confirm why you think this is the answer, when the question already has an accepted answer?

Well, he's entirely correct (except for spelling).  The accepted answer is that the show name is "Tranzor Z"; however, that is the dubbed name.  The original Japanese title is "Mazinger Z".
